# Pivots (or origins?) proper positioning

Tags: rendering, animation, import, stl

I want to animate this scene:
[image: pivots out of objects]

How can I place pivots (or origins?) of the objects at proper position, since now pivots are somewhere outside of objects?
Never mind what I'm doing geometry is moving, not pivot.
Is there some simple command as move pivot/origin?

I'll try to find some tutorials on youtube, but on those tutorials guys are step ahead, clicking so fast, using some shortcuts, interface of Blender is different ... etc., so it is not easy to follow.
I watching now some tuts, but they are for clean Blender objects and guys telling what Blender is doing ... not what I need (+tons of shortcuts of course) :)

Regards

Comment: Hi. Please use a title that matches the content of the question. It should be descriptive but succinct, unique and identifying, summarizing the issue so that anyone searching for a similar problem is likely to find it. Remove anything superfluous, avoid using words like "*this*", "*help with*", "*issue*" or "*question about*", instead describe what "it" is. Remember, your title is the first thing potential visitors see, answers you get depend heavily on how insightful it is. See [*What is the problem of asking “How do I do this?"*](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2449)

Comment: Please only ask one question at a time. You can ask as many questions as you like but stick to one problem for each question!

Comment: As John says, please ask one question only. If the origin is not correctly placed you can either move it where the center of rotation is supposed to be, or parent the object to an empty and rotate the empty instead

Comment: Thanks Chris! :)

Comment: @N.B.U if CHris' answer is correct, mark it as such

Answer (score 3):

you can move just the origin (not the mesh) by checking "origin" and then move that point:

[image]